# Difference between MutableList and ListBuffer

Tags: scala, scala-collections

What is the difference between Scala's `MutableList` and `ListBuffer` classes in `scala.collection.mutable`? When would you use one vs the other?

My use case is having a linear sequence where I can efficiently remove the first element, prepend, and append. What's the best structure for this?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

A little explanation on how they work.

`ListBuffer` uses internally `Nil` and `::` to build an immutable `List` and allows constant-time removal of the first *and last* elements. To do so, it keeps a pointer on the first and last element of the list, and is actually allowed to change the head and tail of the (otherwise immutable) `::` class (nice trick allowed by the `private[scala] var` members of `::`). Its `toList` method returns the normal immutable `List` in constant time as well, as it can directly return the structure maintained internally. It is also the default builder for immutable `List`s (and thus can indeed be reasonably expected to have constant-time append). If you call `toList` and then again append an element to the buffer, it takes linear time with respect to the current number of elements in the buffer to recreate a new structure, as it must not mutate the exported list any more.

`MutableList` works internally with `LinkedList` instead, an (openly, not like `::`) mutable linked list implementation which knows of its element and successor (like `::`). `MutableList` also keeps pointers to the first and last element, but `toList` returns in linear time, as the resulting `List` is constructed from the `LinkedList`. Thus, it doesn't need to reinitialize the buffer after a `List` has been exported.

Given your requirements, I'd say `ListBuffer` and `MutableList` are equivalent. If you want to export their internal list at some point, then ask yourself where you want the overhead: when you export the list, and then no overhead if you go on mutating buffer (then go for `MutableList`), or only if you mutable the buffer again, and none at export time (then go for `ListBuffer`).

My guess is that in the 2.8 collection overhaul, `MutableList` predated `ListBuffer` and the whole `Builder` system. Actually, `MutableList` is predominantly useful from within the `collection.mutable` package: it has a `private[mutable] def toLinkedList` method which returns in constant time, and can thus efficiently be used as a delegated builder for all structures that maintain a `LinkedList` internally.

So I'd also recommend `ListBuffer`, as it may also get attention and optimization in the future than “purely mutable” structures like `MutableList` and `LinkedList`.

Comment: I don't think ListBuffer allow constant-time get/remove last element! see [ListBuffer.scala](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.10.x/src/library/scala/collection/mutable/ListBuffer.scala)

Comment: You're right — seems it doesn't. Too bad, because it easily could.

Comment: What does '::' mean in this answer?

Comment: @KamalChandraprakash `a :: as` returns a new sequence with the element `a` prepended to the existing sequence `as`.

Answer (score 7):

This gives you an overview of the performance characteristics: http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections.html ; interestingly, `MutableList` and `ListBuffer` do not differ there. The documentation of `MutableList` says it is used internally as base class for `Stack` and `Queue`, so maybe `ListBuffer` is more the official class from the user perspective?

Answer (score 5):

You want a list (why a list?) that is *growable*  and *shrinkable*, and you want constant append and prepend. Well, `Buffer`, a trait, has constant append and prepend, with  most other operations linear. I'm guessing that `ListBuffer`, a class that implements `Buffer`, has constant time removal of the first element.

So, my own recommendation is for `ListBuffer`.

Answer (score 3):

First, lets go over some of the relevant types in Scala

**`List`** - An Immutable collection. A Recursive implementation i.e . i.e An instance of list has two primary elements the head and the tail, where the tail references another `List`.

```
List[T]
  head: T
  tail: List[T]  //recursive
```

**`LinkedList`** - A mutable collection defined as a series of linked nodes, where each node contains a value and a pointer to the next node.

```
Node[T]
  value: T
  next: Node[T]  //sequential

LinkedList[T]
  first: Node[T]
```

List is a functional data structure (immutability) compared to LinkedList which is more standard in imperative languages.

Now, lets look at

**`ListBuffer`** - A mutable buffer implementation backed by a **`List`**.

**`MutableList`** - An implementation based on LinkedList ( Would have been more self explanatory if it had been named **`LinkedListBuffer`** instead )

[They both offer similar complexity bounds on most operations.](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/performance-characteristics.html)

However, if you request a `List` from a `MutableList`, then it has to convert the existing linear representation into the recursive representation which takes O(n) which is what @Jean-Philippe Pellet points out. But, if you request a `Seq` from `MutableList` the complexity is O(1).

So, IMO the choice narrows down to the specifics of your code and your preference. Though, I suspect there is a lot more `List` and `ListBuffer` out there.

Answer (score 0):

Note that ListBuffer is final/sealed, while you can extend MutableList.
Depending on your application, extensibility may be useful.