# Vector or MutableList / ListBuffer for performance

Tags: performance, scala, playframework-2.0, immutability

Apologies if this is a duplicate - I did a few searches and didn't quite find what I need.

We have a performance critical piece of our application that converts a Play 2.0 `Enumerator` (can be thought of as a `Stream`) of incoming data to a `List` (or similar). We will use the `fold` method on `Enumerator` and the question is what will be the most performant way to do it. (I will use `Stream` instead of `Enumerator` in the code, but the idea should be the same.)

```
val incoming: Stream[Int] = ???
val result: Seq[Int] = incoming.fold(Seq.empty)(_ + _)
val result2: Seq[Int] = incoming.fold(MutableList.empty(_ += _).toSeq
```

So the question is essentially, how does repeatedly appending to an immutable `Vector` compare to repeatedly appending to a mutable `MutableList` or `ListBuffer` in performance critical code? We've thrown out just `List` because we need `O(1)` appending (not prepending). But does the mutable data-structure buy us anything in terms of performance or garbage collection?

Comment: why not just use `toList`?

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear - the application uses an Enumerator from Play 2.0 so it's a bit different. I thought using Stream in the example code would be simpler but it made this a little confusing I guess... How should I fix the question?

Comment: partly my fault - I failed to notice that you mentioned `Stream`. It should be enough to mention in the question that it is a Play 2.0 Enumerator

Comment: Typo? - `val incoming: String[Int]`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5446744/difference-between-mutablelist-and-listbuffer?rq=1 provides a pretty good description of how the two data structures work, and seems to pertain to your use case.

Comment: I think we're gonna go with ListBuffer because of the final conversion to List.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You are probably best off using `ArrayBuffer`.  On my machine, you get about the following number of appends per second:

```
preallocated Array[Int]    -- 830M
resized (x2) Array[Int]    -- 263M
Vector.newBuilder + result -- 185M
mutable.ArrayBuffer        -- 125M
mutable.ListBuffer         -- 100M
mutable.MutableList        --  71M
immutable.List + reverse   --  68M
immutable.Vector           --   8M
```

I assume you're not always just storing ints, and you want all the collections goodness without extra wrappings, so `ArrayBuffer` is the best-performing solution as long as you only need to append to one end.  The lists support bidirectional addition and are comparable.  Vector is horribly slow in comparison--only use it if you can take advantage of a lot of data sharing, or create it all in one swoop (see `Vector.newBuilder` result, which is fantastic; it's a great data structure for access, iteration, and creation and *sparing* updates, not updates-all-the-time).

Comment: I'm surprised about the difference between 'resized (x2) Array[Int]' and `ArrayBuffer` because the latter is based on `ResizableArray` which uses the same resize strategy. Do you know what causes the slow-down ?

Comment: @paradigmatic - Mostly boxing of `Int`.

Comment: The use of `Int` in my example is oversimplification. Also, we do need to convert it to a `List` or at least some `Seq` at the end. `Vector.newBuilder` or `ListBuffer` sound the best.

Comment: @RexKerr may I ask how you're creating the perf test output?  Custom code or public?

Comment: @BAR - I don't remember any more what I did.  I do this sort of thing _all_ the time.  I probably used my own benchmarking tool, Thyme, but I might have used Caliper.

Comment: @RexKerr Thanks Rex, I implemented my own.

Comment: What does `Vector.newBuilder` mean?

Comment: @StephenBoesch - Builders build a particular type of collection.  So it means something like `val b = Vector.newBuilder[Int]; ...(code)... b += x ...(more code)...; b.result` to produce a `Vector[Int]`.  (If you want to stick in a whole collection of things, you can do `b ++= xs`

Comment: OK different question: the `Vector.newBuilder+result` outperforms anything but preallocated `Array` so why do you recommend `ArrayBuffer` ?

Comment: @StephenBoesch - Because a builder isn't a collection, so you can't do anything useful with it until you're completely done building.  If you don't want to use the collection early (i.e. first you build, then you use), a builder is preferable.